# Meteor.js not running on local host - error (changed MONGO_URL)

Tags: mongodb, heroku, meteor

I was trying to run export MONGO_URL=mongolab url in the interest of syncing up my mongodb with my heroku instance (it was running fine previously).  Now it is not working on production or local host (where it was working before.

Now the application is not working on localhost (it was working fine before, and I was able to see collection data in Robomongo).

I ran:

export `MONGO_URL=mongodb://dbusername:dbpassword@ds22233.mongolab.com:22233/dbname`

Then trying to change it back I ran:

```
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017
```

What can I do to change it back?
(very frustrated)

Also if you have any information on how to get my mongolab db to work with heroku, that would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the localhost db working again, your URL should be mongodb://localhost:27017/yourdbname - yourdbname is probably meteor as that is the default.